# How do I set up a wireless network with a computer using a usb modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a Verizon usb modem and I want to make a wireless network with my Linksys E1200 router. The problem is I cannot plug router into modem with ethernet cable. Can I connect ethernet cable to computer and do it that way? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you set this up. You will need your modem, computer, switch and wireless access point.

Plug the modem into the USB port of the computer.

Plug the ethernet port into the computer and then into the switch.

Connect your other computers to the to the access point normally.

On the primary computer with the USB modem, you will want to go to your network connections and to the properties of your USB modem.

[image]

You will want to check the box where it says to Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection.

When using a router, you will want to plug the computer into the WAN Port of the access point.